# PHP: Prepend/append string to a variable

Tags: php, string, append

so I have been trying to wrap my head around this thing few hours,
but nothing seems to work as expected.

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($lines); $i++){
  $currentLine = $lines[$i];
  $search  = array('ø', '', 'ï', 'ò');$replace = array('ř', 'ť', 'ď', 'ň');
  $subject = str_replace($search, $replace, $currentLine);
  $finalLine = '"'.$subject.'",';
  file_put_contents($fileName, $finalLine, FILE_APPEND);
};
```

The thing is simple, I am iterating over lines in .dic file (it's just list of words, one word at a line),
for each word I do some replacing of wrong characters and at the end of all I try to **wrap the word in double quotes** (single quotes don't work either).

**The problem is**, that the quotes aren't added correctly, and instead of `"someword",` i get `","someword`

```
// $currentLine = someword;
echo '"'.$currentLine.'",';

// returns
","someword
```

I need this to convert .dic file to json so i can use it in javascript game i am making.

Can someone please help? I can't find any similar question, not here, not on google, nothing. I tried single quotes, i tried making the whole thing array

```
$newline = Array(
  0 => '"',
  1 => $currentLine,
  2 => '",'
)
```

and then joining the array but with the same result, I am kinda desperate now, so if someone knows what am I doing wrong, please tell me.

Comment: This should work, you concatenate the line between quotes, so the output should also be between quotes

Comment: And for json - there's `json_encode` and not the wheels, you're inventing here.

Comment: It might be your intent, but you do know that you are appending to ` $finalLine` and then also appending `$finalLine` to the `$fileName` file after every loop iteration?

Comment: @Chris oh my bad, I must have left that there from another unsuccessful try.

Comment: Are you appending one line at a time because the .dlc file is very large?

Comment: @Greg Yes, it's about 900000 lines, 15MB of data. I need this only once to get the json format. And it's impossible to edit it in Sublime or other editor because it freezes, every time :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell from the code why you are getting that result. But here is an alternative approach that might help.

```
// Set these outside the loop
$search  = array('ø', '', 'ï', 'ò');
$replace = array('ř', 'ť', 'ď', 'ň');

$subjects = array();

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $subject = str_replace($search, $replace, $line);
    $subject = trim($subject); // trim if you want to remove extraneous spaces

    if (!empty($subject)) // Presumably you don't want to add empty lines if there are any
    {
        $subjects[] = $subject;     
    }
}

$allwords = implode(',', $subjects);

file_put_contents($fileName, $allwords, FILE_APPEND);
```

Essentially, create an array of the words, join them with "," using the implode() library function and then add the whole lot to your file.

Comment: Yes that works, but still, i need those words in quotes, because there are some words like "key" "default" "break" and so on, and when i import this file into javascript, it breaks on those words. But thanks, this is still better than what I did. Update: Got it joined with '","', now i just need to add the stating and ending quote. Thanks @Greg.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the quotes but great that you got them added.